# Can't dismiss menu selection IOS - React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, menu, dismiss

I have an issue with the react-native-selection-menu: https://github.com/prscX/react-native-selection-menu

On IOS it's impossible to dismiss the menu without clicking on a value. I want to dismiss it when the user click outside of it or at least add a button cancel. 
By the way it works well on Android.

It seems this component doesn't take a props like isVisible so I can't dismiss it with a change in the state.

There is my code:

```
onPress(props) {
    RNSelectionMenu.Show({
      values: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'],
      selectedValues: [],
      selectionType: 0,
      title: 'Browse by category',
      presentationType: 0,
      enableSearch: false,
      cancellable: true,
      onSelection: selectedValues => {
        console.log('Selected Values: ' + selectedValues);
      },
      isVisible: false,
      // searchTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
    });
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
RNSelectionMenu.Show({
      values: [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five"
      ],
      selectedValues: ["One", "Two"],
      selectionType: 1,
      presentationType: 0,
      enableSearch: false,
      onSelection: selectedValues => {
        console.log("Selected Values: " + selectedValues);
      },
      ...props
    });
```

I am wondering if you forgot to pass a props